# Hide a custom field based on another custom field

Tags: wordpress

I have made a front-end form using [WP User Frontend](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/) where I have an email field with meta key `email` and two checkbox fields (hide email) with option values `Yes (true)` and `No (false)`.

When a user checks `Yes` the post must not show the email address of that user. I can see the checkbox field saving the correct values to the database, and now I want to show or hide the `email` field on the basis of these values.

This is the code I've been using, but I'm not sure why it isn't working:

```
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hide_email', false); ?>
    <p>Email: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'email', true);?></p>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>Email:<?php echo "Email is private";?></p>
<?php endif;  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing that `'hide_email'` is being saved as a boolean and you are trying to output this code in your single post template file, this is how your example would work:

```
<?php if ( ! empty( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hide_email', true ) ) ) : ?>
  <p>Email: <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'email', true ); ?></p>
<?php else : ?>
  <p>Email: E-mail is private</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You had a few syntax errors in the code example in your post. Also, It is important to note that if you pass false as the third argument to the `get_post_meta()` function it will return an array even if the value is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sunny.
the code is working now but post is showing email in both conditions dont know why and yes the changes you made is not showing any errors only it is showing the email in both conditions
thanks,

Comment: Hi Vikas, I have updated my answer to check for an empty/false condition. You need to check the value of hide_email to determine why the first if statement is being triggered

Comment: Hi sunny,
thanks for helping me out , some how i figured it out and i was using two check boxes but when i removed second one it worked.

:)